# Approximate $\pi$ using $tan(\pi/4) = 1$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm asked to approximate $\pi$ with an error of $10^{-3}$ using that $\tan(\pi /4) = 1$ and the Maclaurin series of $\arctan$ that converges for $-1 < x \leq 1$.

$$ \arctan(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (-1)^{i+1} \frac{x^{2i-1}}{2i-1} $$

For the Lagrange form of the remainder, we have that if $\vert f^{(n+1)}(x) \vert \leq M$ in the interval $[0,1]$ then

$$R_n(1) \leq \left\vert \frac{M \; x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}  \right\vert =\left\vert \frac{M }{(n+1)!}  \right\vert  $$

Where $R_n(x)$ is the remainder or the error. But I have problems findings this $M$, every time I derivate $f(x)=\arctan(x)$ the values of $f^{(n)}(x)$ at the interval $[0,1]$ get bigger and I can't find a general expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$ . Is there any way to find this $M_n$ such that $ \vert f^{(n)}(x)\vert \leq M_n $ ?

I find out using the computer that for an error of $10^{-m}$ I need $10^m$ terms of the sum, there must be a relation in some part.

Comment: I'm given that $R_n(1) < 0.001$ but I still need that $M_n$

Comment: yes, $M_n$ is $M$

Comment: @AhmadBazzi I think that $M$ is defined by the OP as the max value of the $(n+1)$th derivative of $f$ in the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: thanks @Mason  ..

Comment: $E_n = R_n$ and yes $M$ is the max value of the (n+1)th derivate of $f$ in $[0,1]$

Comment: Well you could compute the [max values](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=max+(4th+derivative+arctan(x))+from+%5B0,1%5D) for various derivatives and see if pattern emerges. I doubt there will be  a clean pattern. I wonder if we can bound $M_n$ above though.

Comment: Isn't the last step of this whole process going to be multiplying the whole thing by $4$? Won't that multiply your error by 4? In this case we need $R_n(1)<0.00025$ 
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mqx0ptt14v. $n=999$ does the trick. $n=998$ isn't quite sufficient.

Comment: yes, the last step is multiplied by $4$, but it is an undergraduate class of Calculus and I need to prove it  without using a computer

Comment: Using computer I find out that for an error of 10^(-n) I need 10^n elements of the series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the alternating series theorem to bound the error.  The error is of the sign of the first neglected term and smaller than it.  Since the $501^{st}$ term is $+\frac 1{1001}$ you are there.